# Is it possible create a new branch using Azure devops tasks Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

Good morning,

I would like create a new branch from devel to create the branch of production, only using a task in azure devops, is it possible? I'm searching in marketplace if exists any good option.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean just to add some pipeline task, no. But you may consider using of:

1. Git commands: [Run Git commands in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).
2. Rest API: [Create/Update/Delete a ref by repositoryId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/update-refs?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#examples), [Get started sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/rest/samples?view=azure-devops)
3. AZ commands: [az repos ref create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/ref?view=azure-cli-latest)